# Node.js , multer, express, sequelize, Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, multer

i am currently trying to store images in my database.

Here is my posts model:-

```
id: {
field: "PostId",
type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
primaryKey: true,
},
title: {
type: Sequelize.STRING,
},
images: {
type: Sequelize.STRING
}
```

and here is my post request:-

```
router.post(
"/",
 [
 upload.array("images", config.get("maxImageCount")),
 imageResize,
 ],
 async (req, res) => {
const paths = await req.files.map((file) => ({ fileName: file.filename }));
Posts.create({
  title: req.body.title,
  images: JSON.stringify(paths),
}).then(
  () => {
    res.status(201).send({
      msg: "upload successful",
    });
  },
  (validation) => {
    res.status(422).json({
      errors: validation.errors.map((error) => {
        return {
          fieldName: error.path,
          message: error.message,
        };
      }),
    });});});
```

i am using multer to store my images on the disk for now and sharp to resize my images.

my problem is when i go to localhost/posts this is how the images look:-

```
`"images":"[{\"fileName\":\"95aa17.‌​png-2020-11-08T14:24‌​:33.221Z\"},{\"fileN‌​ame\":\"fwfe.pn‌​g-2020-11-08T14:24:3‌​3.268Z\"}]"`
```

when it is supposed to look like this:-

```
`"images":"[{"fileName":"95aa17.‌​png-2020-11-08T14:24‌​:33.221Z"},{"fileN‌​ame":"fwfe.pn‌​g-2020-11-08T14:24:3‌​3.268Z"}]"`
```

After hours of research i found out that for best practise i should not use JSON.stringify on an array.

How should i solve this problem?

Comment: With the same problem. Any improvement?

Comment: Do you need save in your database filepaths or BLOB?

Comment: I have posted the answer to this question below please have a look and comment if you need further explanation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i managed to solve this problem. Here is the solution:

```
router.post(
"/",
[
upload.array("images", config.get("maxImageCount")),
imageResize,
],
async (req, res) => {
const paths = await req.files.map((file) => ({ fileName: file.filename }));
Posts.create({
title: req.body.title,
images: paths.map((x) => ({ images: x.fileName }));
}).then(
() => {
res.status(201).send({
  msg: "upload successful",
});
},
(validation) => {
res.status(422).json({
  errors: validation.errors.map((error) => {
    return {
      fieldName: error.path,
      message: error.message,
    };
  }),
});});});
```

I am storing the images as fileNames in the database.